# Covariance of Gaussian process?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, covariance, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

**Problem:**

Consider the random process defined by the Ito integral
$$ X_t = \int_0^t f(\tau)\, dB_\tau $$
where $f(\tau)$ is a deterministic real-valued function and $B_\tau$ denotes the canonical real-valued Wiener process.

I want to find the (presumably multivariate normal) distribution of $X_t$ for $t \in [0,T]$.

**Expectation:**

Since $X_t$ is an Ito integral and $f(\tau)$ is deterministic, I know that $\mathbb{E}(X_t) = 0$ for all $t$.

**Variance:**

From the Ito isometry I have that
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ \left( \int_0^t f(\tau)\, dB_\tau \right)^2 \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t f(\tau)^2\, d\tau \right]. $$

**Autocovariance:**

This is where I am stuck. How would I go about finding the autocovariance function of $X_t$
$$ \mathrm{cov}(X_t,X_s) = \mathbb{E}(X_t X_s) $$
where $s \in (0,t)$?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of using $X_t=X_s+(X_t-X_s)$?

Comment: Using the independence of $X_s$ and $(X_t-X_s)$ I get $\mathrm{cov}(X_s,X_t)=\mathrm{Var}(X_s)$. Intuitively this seems strange as it implies a covariance which does not decay with distance between $s$ and $t$.

Comment: It doesn't. But the *correlation* does.